# Can a 'Recommended' Filter be added to the search criteria of Tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, searching

At present users are able to filter their Tag searches by Info, Newest, FAQ, Votes, Active and Unanswered

Would it be possible to add a Recommended filter also.

For instance if [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) were to be added to the Recommended filter for the Tags Installation, Boot and Black-screen, users are more likely to find answers they are looking for faster.

To keep the Recommended filter less cluttered, only users with a very high reputation should be allowed to add questions to it.

I suppose in some way it would be the equivalent of a 'sticky' found on forums.

Comment: We technically already keep a list of frequently asked items in some meta, i forget where it is.  We keep a canonical list of questions though, just need to find the thing.  :P

Answer (score 2):

This site already handles this sort of thing for frequently asked questions.

While a person is writing out their question the site is automatically populating the right side column with recommended duplicates and similar questions. So as I am typing "black screen on install" it's adding those as recommended duplicates.

The way to strengthen this sort of thing is to continue cross linking and duplicating questions/answers when appropriate. This helps the generated FAQ be more relevant to users. So for example here is the list of current FAQs for all tags:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions?sort=faq

These cover a bunch of topics and we know is generated by views, votes, and other things that make us know they're real FAQs, not user curated, I think if you just think of this tab as Recommended then it's basically what you're looking for?

I'm not really sure what problem having "stickies" would solve, no one would read them, if you could maybe clear up your question with more detail on what you feel the main issue is then that would help.